# How to implement classic javascript functions in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I continue working on my meteor app, and am currently facing a new problem.
I'm still not a level 100 master of Meteor.js, but I kinda start to know it.

But today I discovered but challenges :

- The first is that I want my textarea to grow automatically in height
  as I'm typing, exactly like facebook do it, without a drag option.
  For that, I've tried to implement 2 different solutions : the first
  being to call the Jquery autogrow() function, the second one being to
  code my own function to modify the css number of row. Unfortunately,
  none of them gave me a result.
- The second challenge I face is that i want to make my 
  bootstrap compliant, exactly like it is described here :
  http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

The problem being : no matter in which js file I enable Bootstrap-select, or allow the textarea to autogrow(), nothing happens.

So here is my question : when I build a meteor app, where and how do i implement such function from bootstrap and JQuery ? What are the good habits to have, the tips I should know to improve my app structure and fonctionnality ?

Edit : here is my select code, when i apply the solution proposed by Ethan, i do well get the css applied, but the select doesn't deploy anymore by clicking on it.

```
<div class="well">
       <h3>Account informations :</h3>
       <label for="bio">My presentation :</label>
       <textarea id="bio" rows="5" cols="100" placeholder="Present yourself (hobbies, job...)"></textarea><br>
       <label for="nativeLang">I speak :</label>
       <select class="show-tick" id="nativeLang" data-style="btn-primary" data-live-search="true" data-max-options="2" multiple>
         {{#each isoLangs}}
           {{>isoLang}}
         {{/each}}
       </select><br>
       <label for="learningLang">I want to practice :</label>
       <select class="" id="learningLang" data-style="btn-primary" data-live-search="true" multiple>
         {{#each isoLangs}}
           {{>isoLang}}
         {{/each}}
       </select><br>
     </div>
```

Thanks you,

David

Comment: Everything is on the docs. Just read it 2 3 times from top to bottom. It will save you a lot of time in the long run.

Comment: Yes, i thinks I'm going to do that once again !

Comment: We would also need your helpers code to understand what's happening in your template. Also, you shouldn't ask about "good habits"! It's generally a matter of opinion and might earn your question some flags. Instead, stick to cold hard facts (issues, solutions, ...). Please [edit] your question to add all relevant information and remove opinionated questions. You should also describe more in depth what "none of them gave me a result" means.